# 'function' : cannot convert from 'double' to 'wchar_t *'

Tags: c, visual-studio, wchar-t

I am trying to compile in visual studio 2010, and this is the exact error I get:

```
Error 65 error C2440: 'function' :
       cannot convert from 'double' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

The offending line being:

```
swprintf(subbuf[num], L"%f\0", va_arg(args, double));
```

This is supposed to compile cleanly so code changes are not recommended.
Am I missing any compiler option which might resolve this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the declaration of `subbuf`:

```
#define GDB_CHAR wchar_t
GDB_CHAR subbuf[MAX_SUBS][STATUS_MSG_LEN+1] ;
```

Also, regarding the size argument, I also checked the documentation page, however, compiler
doesn't throw an error on

```
swprintf(subbuf[num], L"%c\0", va_arg(args, int));
```

So it has no issues in converting from `int` to `wchar_t *` and the function's arguments are ok.

If this is still not informative enough, please comment and direct me to any other you guys need.
Thanks

Comment: What type is `subbuf`? (Also, you should remove the C++ tag if this is C code and vice-versa.)

Comment: This cannot possibly compile, you use identifiers which are not declared. Until you post a useful code snippet, you cannot expect to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Deepak: Potatoswatter's answer is right. It's not surprising that your compiler let's you implicitly convert `int` to a pointer (you probably should choose a higher warning level), but it *cannot* sensibly convert a double to a pointer. Why don't you just try to use the right arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick glance at the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwprintf.html) shows that the function requires an argument specifying the size of the output string, which you have omitted.